# start gas vs gas limit

Tags: mining, gas, fees

To be absolutely sure: `start gas` and `gas limit` are the same thing in ***[the context of a transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#gas-and-fees)***, correct?

Comment: `STARTGAS` is the EVM language. What it means is "gas limit". It's like how you can call `exception` "error"

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, could you please mark it so other users know. :)

Comment: I wanted to make sure my question was clear for future readers. After reading it over, I _was_ asking about `gas limit` in the context of a transaction, not block.

Comment: @bvpx good question, it can be confusing I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that context, yes they are the same thing.

A `start gas` value, represents the maximum number of computational steps the transaction execution can take (unused gas is refunded to the account sender).

Miner of the block receives a reward of `(startgas - gas_rem) * gasprice`.

If a transaction "***runs out of gas***" mid-execution, then all execution reverts, but the transaction is nevertheless valid, and the only effect of the transaction is to transfer the entire sum `startgas * gasprice` to the miner.

If a user specifies a gas value that is **too low**, then it’s common for clients (e.g. Geth) to throw an error telling the user that they’re not purchasing enough gas for this transaction to be executed. In contrast if the user sets the gas **too high** then they may be effectively spending more gas that what was originally intended.

You can think of this as the total amount of gas a sender is willing to purchase for the transaction to be executed i.e. `gas limit` or it's often referred to as `gasUsed`.

Additionally, `gas limit` is referenced when talking about blocks. They too, have a field called `gas limit`. It defines the maximum amount of gas all transactions in the whole block combined are allowed to consume. Please see [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39132/what-is-gas-limit-in-ethereum).

Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

**Gas:**

The gas or `startGas` is the amount of gas you send along with your transaction (the gas parameter of `sendTransaction`).

There is a fixed amount of gas a computational step consumes. The remaining gas is refunded. For eg, transferring ether consumes 21000 gas.
Now if you supply 30,000 gas while sending plain ethers (without any data),  the remaining 9,000 (30,000-21,000) will be refunded.

**Gas Price:**

This is the price which we normally pay for our gas. When we set `gasPrice` as `2 Gwei`, we mean to say that we are willing to pay 2Gwei per gas.

So when you send a transaction (let's consider sending plain ether) with 30,000 gas and 2Gwei gasPrice. The fee that you will pay to miners is (21000*2 GWi).

**Gas Limit:**

The `gasLimit` which mainly is used to refer to `blockGasLimit` is the max amount of gas that all transactions of the block together can have.

For eg, Let's say there are 3 transactions A,B, C with gas being 1000,2000 and 3000 respectively and suppose blockGasLImit is 4000. SO in a block can contain only following set of transactions, AC, AB. BC cannot be included in same block because their cumulative gas (3000+2000) is greater than block gas limit (4000) .

The concept of gas and gasPrice is much wider and there are plenty of examples and articles explaining that. Just google and you will get much-elaborated answers.